# Jest/Enzyme: How to handle an async function being called inside another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to run Jest/Enzyme async tests for `fetchTemperatures` and I've run into a bit of unfamiliar ground. If I define longitude and latitude and comment out `getUserCoordinates` I am able to pass my tests. Question is, how can I write my tests to allow/mock that an async function inside of `fetchTemperatures` is returning values?

~ additionally, if there are any other issues with how the code is written please let me know, I am trying to warm back up to the js environment...

**fetchTemperatures.js**

```
export const fetchTemperatures = async (format = 'weather', source = 'openWeather') => {
    // for 5-day-forecast set format arg to "forecast"
    try {
        let response;
        const { longitude, latitude } = await getUserCoordinates();
        //! the nested async above is preventing me from running the tests...
        // let longitude = 100;
        // let latitude = 100;
        if (source === 'openWeather') {
            response = await fetch(
                `${openWeatherURL}/${format}?APPID=${process.env
                    .REACT_APP_OW_API_KEY}&lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&units=imperial`
            );
        } else if (source === 'darkSky') {
            response = await fetch(
                `${darkSkyURL}${process.env
                    .REACT_APP_DS_API_KEY}/${latitude},${longitude}?exclude=[currently,minutely,hourly,flags]`
            );
        } else {
            //! is this getting hit? -- not sure
            throw new Error("Enter a valid source string. Ex: 'openWeather' or 'darkSky'");
        }
        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Fetch failed');
    }
};
```

**fetchTemperatures.test.js**

```
describe('fetchTemperatures()', () => {
    let mockResponse = { data: 'Weather related data.' };
    let response;
    beforeAll(() => {
        window.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return Promise.resolve({
                ok: true,
                json: () => Promise.resolve(mockResponse)
            });
        });
        //! Number of calls: 0 === FIGURE OUT NESTED ASYNC IN SOURCE
        response = fetchTemperatures();
    });

    // argument-based routes
    it('args=default, should call fetch with the correct url', () => {
        fetchTemperatures();
        expect(window.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            `${openWeatherURL}/weather?APPID=${process.env
                .REACT_APP_OW_API_KEY}&lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&units=imperial`
        );
    });
    it('args="weather", should call fetch with the correct url', () => {
        fetchTemperatures('forecast');
        expect(window.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            `${openWeatherURL}/weather?APPID=${process.env
                .REACT_APP_OW_API_KEY}&lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&units=imperial`
        );
    });
    it('args="weather", "darkSky", should call fetch with the correct url', () => {
        fetchTemperatures('weather', 'darkSky');
        expect(window.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            `${darkSkyURL}${process.env
                .REACT_APP_DS_API_KEY}/${latitude},${longitude}?exclude=[currently,minutely,hourly,flags]`
        );
    });

    // success
    it('Success::Promise Resolve: should return with the current weather', () => {
        response.then((results) => {
            expect(results).toEqual(mockResponse);
        });
    });

    // failure - success but response not ok
    it('Failure::Response !ok: should return an error', () => {
        window.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return Promise.resolve({
                ok: false
            });
        });
        expect(fetchTemperatures()).rejects.toEqual(Error('Fetch failed'));
    });

    // failure - reject
    it('Failure::Promise Rejects', () => {
        window.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return Promise.reject(Error('Fetch failed'));
        });
        expect(fetchTemperatures()).rejects.toEqual(Error('Fetch failed'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward to mock `getUserCoordinates`, you have a few different options:

1. You can use `jest.mock`, which takes the path to the module containing `getUserCoordinates` and intercepts it, returning the mocked value from the callback you provide:

```js
// This assumes `getUserCoordinates` is a named export.
// If it's the default export just have the callback return jest.fn()...
jest.mock('./get-user-coordinates.js', () => ({
  getUserCoordinates: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({lat: 0, long: 0});
}));
```

2. You could also use `import * as`, which allows you to mock imports without `jest.mock`:

```js
// You can name `api` whatever you want
import * as api from './get-user-coordinates';

api.getUserCoordinates = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({lat: 0, long: 0});
```

One other thing: In your third-to-last test, you should make sure to *return* `response.then()...`, otherwise your test will pass before waiting to enter the `.then()` block:

```js
// Returning the promise makes the test wait until the
// `.then` is executed before finishing.
return response.then((results) => {
  expect(results).toEqual(mockResponse);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I may have to just back off and read more into the documentation since I'm still not getting it. I'm not sure where to plug that mock in so that it actually plays nice with the subsequent tests. 

As of right now, when I try to plug that command into the `BeforeAll` block i get the error: 

`: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:`.

Comment: Sorry to hear you haven’t been able to get it working! Here’s the example from the jest docs, maybe this will help: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules ... also, you might try changing beforeAll to beforeEach...